# Why all variables in tensorflow are preferred to reside on the cpu

Tags: scope, tensorflow

Can anyone tell me what is advantage of forcing all variables to reside on the CPU as is done in the tensorflow inception v3 code ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_train.py#L233)) or in the cifar10 code ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py#L132))? Do the variables not need to reside on the GPUs too, for executing the forward or backward computation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people have observed that putting variables on GPU:0 in cifar10 makes things faster, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4881

It makes sense to keep parameters on CPU when you don't have P2P transfer capability between your GPUs.

Comment: Thanks @Yaroslav. Following the issue I found that my two GPUs have P2P connectivity. In that case I'd keep the variables on gpu:0. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to append to the comment above - The console output for P2P connectivity is as follows

Comment: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:972] DMA: 0 1 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] 0:   Y Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] 1:   Y Y